# Firebase onWrite Trigger - Disable trigger on update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How do I do this? I used the code below but it is not working. I still receive notification when I update my Database

```js
exports.sendNewPostNotif = functions.database.ref('/News/{ID}').onWrite(event => {


    const announce_data = event.data.val();
    const announce_data_type = announce_data.categ_post; 
    const announce_data_title = announce_data.title_post; 
    const announce_data_uid = announce_data.uid; id
    const announce_post_key = announce_data.postkey; 

    if(!event.data.val()) {
        return console.log('No data');
    } 

    if(event.data.previous.exist()) {

        return;
    }
```

Whenever I send a new content, it'll go through the onWrite event then send the notification. Mmy current issue is whenever I edit the post, it'll send a notification which I do not require. I tried the above and it works as I receive no notification when I update the news content BUT I don't receive a notification when I create a new content.

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's going to be hard to help. We're missing a lot of context here. Where is this code running? What is `event`?

Comment: It's similiar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677506/determining-whether-data-is-added-or-deleted-to-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: Sorry if i confuses you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it possible to use event.data.key to check if it has existed before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want your function to run when the node is created, and not when it is updated or deleted, you can use the `onCreate` trigger:

```
exports.sendNewPostNotif = functions.database.ref('/News/{ID}').onCreate(event => {
```

See the [Firebase documentation on database trigger types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_database_function) and the [blog post where these are introduced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html).

Comment: Nice! Thank you, Frank.